# Error while publishing an EF Core Angular app to Azure App service

Tags: sql-server, angular, azure, azure-web-app-service, ef-core-2.2

One year back I have worked for a project using the EF Core Angular app (.NET Core 2.1). Now we got some modification to the existing application. So when I try to execute the same application by changing the connection string in the `appsettings.json` file, it's working fine in local machine. But when I try to publish it in Azure app service it's giving some irrelevant error.

Note: The database is in an Azure VM earlier and now. But when we stop the VM and start the IP will be changed so we need to change only the connection string.

[image]

I tried installing all the run time SDK and host bundles. But it doesn't work. I wonder when it is working fine in local, Why it's not getting published in Azure.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Usually encountered this problem, it is difficult to directly locate the wrong place. My suggestion is that you first download and save your .publish file, then delete your publishing configuration, and then recreate the webapp and publish it for testing. If it can run normally, then compare the new .publish file with the previous file.

Comment: Regarding the configuration of the database, it is recommended to set it in the portal, where the Connection strings have priority over the configuration in the web.config file.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for your suggestions. I have fixed the issue by commenting the some of the lines in .csproj file.

Comment: I'm glad you can solve this problem. If you can, I suggest you share the solution to the forum where you can help more. Because I'm not sure what operations you have done in the project, I can only suggest to delete and redeploy.

Comment: @vamsi Congratulations that you solved the problem by yourself. I help you post it as answer, then others can know that. You may think about mark it as answer or post it yourself with some details. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @vamsi, you also could post an answer by yourself and mark it. Then I will delete mine.  Thanks~

Answer (score 1):

Congratulations that the issue is error is solved by @vamsi himself:

"I have fixed the issue by commenting the some of the lines in .csproj file."